# Unix pipeline command for redirecting output from stdin to stderr

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script that outputs information about successes to stdout, and also does a grep looking for errors in logs

inner.sh:

```
# do some things
echo success
# do other things
echo success

grep 'error' logs/*
```

I have another shell script that calls this one, counts up the successes and compares them to an expected number of successes:

outer.sh:

```
bash ./inner.sh | grep success | wc -l # I compare this number to the expected number
```

What I can't figure out how to do is have the output of `grep` go to stderr, so its not counted by the `wc -l` in `outer.sh`, but rather makes it around the `wc` to the terminal for the operator to see.

So I want a command like `stdin_to_stderr` that I can pipe the `grep` to, that would make any results it finds leave `inner.sh` on its stderr.

Is there already such a thing? Or do I just need to write the tiny script that would do this? Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: `grep success >&2`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to count with `wc -l` in `outer.sh` - number of lines printed by `inner.sh`?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. This line `bash ./inner.sh | grep success | wc -l` will correctly count all lines that contain `success`. I think that your confusion stems from the fact that you think that `grep` will add its output to output produced by `inner.sh` but it's not the case.

Comment: OK I have never seen the `>&2` construction, I think that's what i need. To answer your question 'what do I want to do count with `wc -l` ', I want to count the number of times success appears in the stdout of inner.sh, but let any failures show up out-of-band on the console.

Comment: Why wouldn't `grep`'s output come out the stdout of `inner.sh`?

Comment: It would. You'd see two lines that say `sucess` *both* when you run it with `grep` and when you run it without `grep`. I still don't understand what problem you're having.

Comment: You don't need `wc`, you can use `grep -c success`.

Comment: Oh good point on grep -c. I'll use that. Thanks Freddy.

Answer (score 0):

```
bash ./inner.sh >&2 output_log_file

grep -c success output_log_file  -- Count of success 
grep -v -c success output_log_file -- Count of not "success"
```

Example :

```
echo -e "success.\nerror.\nsuccess.\nError.\nsuccess.\nerror" |  grep -c success

echo -e "success.\nerror.\nsuccess.\nError.\nsuccess." |  grep -v -c success
```

output :

```
3
2
```